# Scraping news article data and formatting the results in Word

Tags: python, ms-word, web-scraping

For a list of article URLs I need to scrape the title, author, date, publication, and body of the article. Then each article needs to appear in Word, formatted according to a template (bold title, pub in italics, table of contents at the top with hyperlinks etc).

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi there. We encourage posters to show us what they have tried so far, partly to encourage them to try, partly so we can see what specifically needs assistance, and also to discourage posters who will not make an effort at all. With that in mind, if you can edit in what you have, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've used some of this in the past and I would recommend you two things to clean an HTML code and get the text:

- [**html2text**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text/2014.12.29): Library to get text from html code
- [**Regular expressions**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html): Python module which you can use to delete HTML expressions

(Be careful with RegEx, it's possible to miss some data or some string in some cases)

For Word I would recommend this:

- [**python-docs**](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/): Library to work with MS Word into Python.

PS: This is just a little resume. You would have a lot of results if you just use the SO searcher.